# how to add tow or more than two input box values in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, validation, numbers, parseint

i have 110 text boxes and i wanted to sum the values which are available in those 110 text boxes, few may have values so i have written code like below but it is does not give me the correct value  in fact it does not even takes the value which are available in text boxes.

following is my code :

```
var cerTotal =0;

for (var i=1;i<=110;i++)
    {
        if(global.getElementById('CIMtrek_CI_Act_'+i)){
            cerTotal = Number(cerTotal) + Number(global.getElementById('CIMtrek_CI_Act_'+i).value);
        }
    }
```

Please help me to find the problem.

Best Regards

Comment: What is `global`? Shouldn't it be `document`?

Comment: var global = window.document

Comment: You should check if the value not equal 0 or blank, because if 110 text fields are available then your if condition never failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" id="CIMtrek_CI_Act_1" />
<input type="text" id="CIMtrek_CI_Act_2" />
<input type="text" id="CIMtrek_CI_Act_3" />
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="sumUp()" value="SUM" />


<script>
function sumUp() {
   var cerTotal = 0;
   for (var i = 1; i <= 110; i++) {
     if (document.getElementById('CIMtrek_CI_Act_' + i) &&
         document.getElementById('CIMtrek_CI_Act_' + i).value != '') {
           cerTotal += parseFloat(document.getElementById('CIMtrek_CI_Act_' + i).value);
        }
   }
   alert(cerTotal);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `global` is defined, you have the wrong operator. You are assigning your total for each iteration, you should do this instead

```
 cerTotal += ...
```